# How to break row of dataframe based on condition in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe but wants to break the row of dataframe into multiple rows based on condition.

Example:

df:

```
Queue_Id,nOffered_count,nOffered_sum,nOffered.denominator,nOffered.numerator,Interval Start,Interval End,Queue_Id,nOffered_count,nOffered_sum,nOffered.denominator,nOffered.numerator,Interval Start,Interval End,Queue_Id,nTransferred_count,nTransferred_sum,nTransferred.denominator,nTransferred.numerator,Interval Start,Interval End,Queue_Id,nOffered_count,nOffered_sum,nOffered.denominator,nOffered.numerator,Interval Start,Interval End,Queue_Id,nOffered_count,nOffered_sum,nOffered.denominator,nOffered.numerator,Interval Start,Interval End
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,6,,,,2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,1.0,,,,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,12.0,,,,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,6.0,,,,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,6.0,,,,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,1,,,,2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2.0,,,,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,1.0,,,,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,3.0,,,,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,1.0,,,,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z
786db522-4ddd-40a9-aae7-d4d53fb060d2,,,,,2021-10-11T11:46:25,2021-10-18T11:49:48,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
fc7f1974-7dfd-4fa1-91fc-4a87f5133696,,,,,2021-10-11T11:46:25,2021-10-18T11:49:48,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Change this dataframe into below format-

```
Queue_Id,Interval Start,Interval End,nOffered_count,nOffered_sum,nOffered.denominator,nOffered.numerator,nTransferred_count,nTransferred_sum,nTransferred.denominator,nTransferred.numerator
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,6,,,,,,,
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,1.0,,,,,,,
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,12.0,,,,,,,
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,6.0,,,,,,,
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z,6.0,,,,,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,1,,,,,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2,,,,1.0,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,3,,,,,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z,1,,,,,,,
786db522-4ddd-40a9-aae7-d4d53fb060d2,2021-10-11T11:46:25,2021-10-18T11:49:48,,,,,,,,
fc7f1974-7dfd-4fa1-91fc-4a87f5133696,2021-10-11T11:46:25,2021-10-18T11:49:48,,,,,,,,
```

condition is -

`Queue_Id` is coming multiple times in a row so row will break when Queue_Id will come again. `Interval Start` & `Interval End` Should come only one time and rest of the columns should fill as it with their respective values.

Comment: And what is the condition?

Comment: condition is - 

@Timus `Queue_Id` is coming multiple times in a row so row will break when Queue_Id will come again. `Interval Start` & `Interval End` Should come only one time and rest of the columns should fill as it with their respective values.